# Programmatically retrieve Maven dependency graph

Tags: java, maven, ivy

Given a Maven artifact (groupId:artifactId:version), how can I programmatically query its dependencies? (I don't need actually retrieve any artifacts, just the dependency information.)

**Edit to add** I'd like to do this outside of a Maven plug-in, and I'd like to build up a dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a maven plugin (ie: extend AbstractMojo), you can do the following:

```
  /**
   * @parameter expression="${project}"
   */
  private org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject mavenProject;

  List<org.apache.maven.model.Dependency> depmgtdeps = mavenProject.getDependencyManagement().getDependencies();
```

That will give you the actual dependency objects that it detects.  The MavenProject class has a bunch of other methods as well for reading various pom related things.  However, I don't believe this works outside a plugin, or at least, I've never tried to do it.

Comment: Thanks -- this is actually not for a Maven plug-in but for a standalone app. Perhaps there's another way to get hold of a MavenProject...

Comment: I'm not sure there is.  There's a constructor that takes a Model, but you don't really have a good way to get one of those either.  Can you provide more info on what you're trying to accomplish here? Might be another way to do what you want.

Comment: I want to build up dependency graphs of various Maven artefacts to test drive a graph-layout algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I found these two links helpful..

1. [A Maven Plugin for retrieving the dependencies](http://el4j.sourceforge.net/plugins/maven-depgraph-plugin/plugin-info.html)
2. [Using Eclipse Plugin](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/04/12/a-visual-maven-dependency-tree-view/)

Answer (score 1):

The following groovy script uses [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to resolve dependencies

```
import groovy.xml.NamespaceBuilder

// Main program
// ============
def ant = new AntBuilder()
def ivy = NamespaceBuilder.newInstance(ant, "antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant")

ivy.resolve(
    inline:true,
    keep:true,
    conf:"default",
    organisation:"org.springframework",
    module:"spring-core",
    revision:"3.1.1.RELEASE",
)

ivy.report(toDir:"reports")
```

Generates a HTML report and a graphml file:

```
|-- report.groovy
|-- reports
|   |-- ivy-report.css
|   |-- org.springframework-spring-core-caller-default.graphml
|   `-- org.springframework-spring-core-caller-default.html
```