# Is there a "build-classpath" equivalent for Ant?

Tags: maven, ant, dependencies, classpath, maven-plugin

I am trying to output the classpath string of dependencies for an ant project. For the Maven project, once achieves this using build-classpath. Anything similar in ANt?

Comment: ANT doesn't have built-in support for classpath management, like Maven. There is an ANT plugin called ivy, which has a "report" task which will print the dependencies associated with each ivy configuration, a concept similar to Maven scopes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417304/ivy-what-is-the-master-configuration-and-why-is-it-not-pulling-jvyaml/11420292#11420292

Comment: Is it possible to invoke the report task programmatically through java?

Comment: Pretty certain it's possible, I don't have examples. I generally use groovy to interact with ANT. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189817/programmatically-retrieve-maven-dependency-graph/11197633#11197633